# Flexbox - wrapping items in sets of 2

Tags: css, flexbox

Got a quick question for anyone familiar with Flexbox.

I have a row of 4 flex items. I'm looking to make it so at the first breakpoint (`max-width:1024px`) they wrap into 2 columns of 2. I thought I might be able to achieve this using a % value on the width of each item inside the flex container but that doesn't seem to work.

The code is here:

http://codepen.io/reskk/pen/rrpdVm

I'm thinking I could achieve this by wrapping the flex items 2 at a time within 2 `<div>`s. However this just creates a lot more work to do with layout and making the page symmetrical.

Is there a way I can do this just using width percentages or something similar?

For example:
25% baseline width - 4 per row
50% width @ 1024px - 2 per row
100% width @ 769px - 1 per row

Thanks,

Rik

Comment: I'm not seeing your attempt to use media queries in your CodePen.

Comment: Look into `flex-wrap: wrap;` if you haven't already. Without it all 4 elements will continue on one line despite max-widths and breakpoints.

Comment: Please include all relevant code as a [mcve], in the question itself, not on a third party site.

Comment: what is "baseline width"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To achieve that, you need to wrap your flex container and set flex-grow & shrink to 0% to children in order to prevent your flex items from (obviously) stretching or shrinking when their content doesn't fit in the desired space (i.e. 25%). Then, you can set flex-basis normally for each breakpoint.

Based on your example, here's what you can do:

```
.whatflex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.con {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px){
  .con{ flex-basis: 50%; }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px){
  .con{ flex-basis: 25%; }
}
```

I've updated your pen [here](https://codepen.io/danmindru/pen/bwavvg?editors=1100#0).

Comment: Hi Dan,

Thanks very much for your help. 

I used the flex-wrap property along with setting widths for the flex items at the 2 breakpoints to achieve exactly the effect I was going for.

Once again thanks mate!

Rik

Comment: Hi Rik, great that you got it to work . If you found my answer helpful, please [accept it & vote up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) :-) Cheers, Dan